# What's the difference between the swedish and swedish - pro keyboard layouts?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

There seem to be two layouts for Swedish (not counting Sami) and I don't understand the difference.

[image]

Comment: If you want to find an answer, you could turn on the keyboard viewer and inspect the keyboards - paying attention to the alternate keys when option, command, shift and control are depressed. You might need to take a screen capture to compare them side by side depending on "photographic" your memory works.

Comment: In case this is not clear - you turn on the Keyboard & Character viewer (from the Keyboard pref) so that it will show as an input source in the preference pane you have uploaded in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell the only difference is that @ and ™ has switched places on the two layouts.

[image: Swedish vs Swedish Pro keyboard layouts on Mac OS]
Screenshots from MacOS High Sierra (10.13.4)

Answer (score 1):

On Macintosh computers, the Swedish and Swedish Pro keyboards differ as regards the characters available using the ⇧ Shift or ⌥ Option keys. ⇧ Shift+§ (on the upper row) produces the ° sign, and ⇧ Shift+4 produces the € sign. The digit keys produce ©@£$∞§|[]≈ with ⌥ Option and ¡”¥¢‰¶{}≠ with ⌥ Option+⇧ Shift.

Answer (score 1):

With "Swedish" the @ sign wasn't available on alt-2, so I had to switch to "Swedish Pro" to get back the "old" behavior.